# Rails Webpacker + Vue mounting delay without webpack-dev-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rendering, webpacker

Mounting delay in production.

When i use webpack-dev-server all components get rendered very fast and work perfectly. However, when I run the application only via `rails s` both in development and in production I can literally see the process of mounting of the Vue app. First I see an html template that comes from server and then my app is being initialized and rendered on client. It's called on demand compilation. But I don't consider this as a normal working code and want to achieve webpack-dev-server like behavior in production.

I have not tried anything, since I don't know what makes webpack-dev-server work perfectly and production mounting so slow.

Also I should say that it's just a CRUD application without complex logic on frontend. So nothing heavy to make mounting so slow.

What do you think where should I start finding the reasons of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/webpacker.yml`, you may have this setting for development

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
```

Which is causing the on-demand compilation.

For the production environment, did you make sure that compile is set to `false`?

```
production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false
```

Your Vue code should be compiled prior to starting your rails server via the `rake assets:precompile` command.

Comment: Samy, thank you for your desire to help!

Yes, ```compile: false``` defined for production environment and Capistrano already handles ```assets:precompile``` task on deploy. The problem is not with initial Vue rendering. It's with mounting in general. When I quickly refresh the page I see the application mounting process.